# mmap() - toggle physical pages in driver

Tags: mmap

A chip might continuously DMA its data out from one (or more) physical page(s) e.g. to refresh an array of LEDs etc.

The driver provides two pages, one for active use by the chip, an inactive one to be prepared with new data by the application. For good performance, the application is given direct access by using mmap().

Once the application has filled the inactive page, it would toggle the two pages via an IOCTL. The driver uses remap_pfn_range() to map the physical page into the user's virtual address space.

However, what seems to be impossible is the swapping of the two pages from an IOCTL, also using remap_pfn_range(). When attempting that I see this:

"Internal error: Oops - BUG: 0 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM" in remap_pfn_range().

Is there any way to replace the underlying physical page for the mmap()'ed area after the initial mapping ?

Of course it would be slightly dangerous playing with that but in a controlled setup this could be acceptable.

Update: It seems as if I could solve this by calling zap_vma_ptes() before mapping a different page via remap_pfn_range(). My test application does see the different content that my test driver placed into its two physical pages when the application switches the mapped page via an IOCTL. I don't know yet whether this has any ill effects, haven't worked in this area before.